# For this ring homomorphism, show that $\ker f$ is a principal ideal and find an element that generates it

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $f : R[x] → R$ be a ring homomorphism defined by $f(r_0 + r_1x + · · · + r_nx^n) = r_0 + r_1 + · · · + r_n$. Prove that $\ker f$ is a principal ideal of $R[x]$ and find an element of
$R[x]$ which generates $\ker f$.

I know $\ker f = \{r\in R:f(r) = 0\}$ and I know that $0 \in R = 0 \in R[x]$.  Also here $f = 0$ iff $\sum_{i=0}^n r_i = 0$, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $p(x)=r_0 + r_1x + · · · + r_nx^n\in\operatorname{ker}(f)$. Then $p(1)= r_0 + r_1 + · · · + r_n=0$. Or $(x-1)\mid p(x)$. And any polynomial which can be written as $(x-1)g(x)$, belongs to $\operatorname{ker}(f)$. Hence $\operatorname{ker}(f)=\langle x-1\rangle$, the ideal generated by $x-1$.

Comment: How do you know (x-1) divides p(x)?

Comment: If you divide $p(x)$ by $x-a$, then the remainder is $p(a)$.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see it.  Could you explain?

Comment: See, by division algorithm, $p(x)=(x-a)Q(x)+R(x)$, where $\operatorname{deg}(R)<\operatorname{deg}(x-a)=1$. Hence $R(x)$ is of degree $0$, and so must be a constant. Now put $x=a$ in the above equation to get $p(a)=R(x)$.

Comment: Oh of course!  Finals have obviously fried my brain. Thank you!